# How do I get what triggered a windowDidMove in my NSWindow?

Tags: cocoa, events, nswindow

I'm debugging a very convoluted code and I'd like to get what cause to trigger a `windowDidMove`, anyone has an idea?
Weird thing is that I change the window's position only once using `setFrameOrigin` however I also receive another `windowDidMove` and at this point the window has position I didn't set. 
I'd like to know (because I'm new with Cocoa) if is possible get which function call caused to trigger `windowDidMove` later on...

Comment: Yes, it is possible but does it matter?

Comment: If you have xcode then its easy. set a breakpoint on mentioned method. If not use lldb to set a breakpoint and then print the stack (bt). More http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html